# Labels Aren't Changing

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm only going to post a snippet of my code, because essentially, it does the same thing.

```
string = ''

time_calc = Tk()
time_calc.geometry('500x400')
time_calc.title("Calculate A Time")
time_calc_frame= Frame(time_calc).grid(row=0, column=0)

jul_box = Entry(time_calc)
jul_box.insert(0, "Julian Date")
jul_box.pack(side = TOP)
jul_box.bind('<Return>')

def jd2gd(jd):
  global string
  jd=jd+0.5
  Z=int(jd)
  F=jd-Z
  alpha=int((Z-1867216.25)/36524.25)
  A=Z + 1 + alpha - int(alpha/4)

  B = A + 1524
  C = int( (B-122.1)/365.25)
  D = int( 365.25*C )
  E = int( (B-D)/30.6001 )

  dd = B - D - int(30.6001*E) + F

  if E<13.5:
            mm=E-1

  if E>13.5:
            mm=E-13

  if mm>2.5:
            yyyy=C-4716

  if mm<2.5:
            yyyy=C-4715

  months=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  daylist=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  daylist2=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

  h=int((dd-int(dd))*24)
  min =int((((dd-int(dd))*24)-h)*60)
  sec=86400*(dd-int(dd))-h*3600-min*60

  # Now calculate the fractional year. Do we have a leap year?
  if (yyyy%4 != 0):
            days=daylist2
  elif (yyyy%400 == 0):
            days=daylist2
  elif (yyyy%100 == 0):
            days=daylist
  else:
            days=daylist2

  hh = 24.0*(dd % 1.0)
  min = 60.0*(hh % 1.0)
  sec = 60.0*(min % 1.0)

  dd =  dd-(dd%1.0)
  hh =  hh-(hh%1.0)
  min =  min-(min%1.0)

  if hh < 10:
    hh = '0%s'%str(int(hh))
  else:
      hh = int(hh)
  if min < 10:
    min = '0%s'%str(int(min))
  else:
      min = int(min)
  if sec < 10:
    sec = '0%s'%str(int(sec))
  else:
      sec = int(sec)

  string = "%s/%s/%s  %s:%s:%s UTC" % (str(int(mm)), str(int(dd)), str(yyyy), str(hh),               str(min), str(sec))
  print string
  return


def j2ghandler():
  jul = float(jul_box.get())

  jd2gd(jul)

j2g_button = Button(time_calc, text='Convert Julian\n to Gregorian', command = j2ghandler, width= 25, pady=5).pack(side=TOP)

#Draw Time String on Canvas
var = StringVar()
var.set(string)
label = Label(time_calc, textvariable=var)
label.pack(side=TOP)
```

I know, "snippet". What should happen when you put in the number and click the button is it should, and does, change the string "string" behind the scenes. I can't get the label to update though. I've tried, as you can see, to use StringVar() to update the label. Also, I tried doing an `.update()` on end of the function but it didn't work.

Any help towards this matter would be greatly appreciated. This is the only part of the application that no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.

Thanks for the help.

PS I didn't include all that `from Tkinter import *`, it's redundant and not necessary for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts in the comment boxes are what I changed:

```
#####################
from Tkinter import *
#####################
string = ''

time_calc = Tk()
time_calc.geometry('500x400')
time_calc.title("Calculate A Time")
time_calc_frame= Frame(time_calc).grid(row=0, column=0)

jul_box = Entry(time_calc)
jul_box.insert(0, "Julian Date")
jul_box.pack(side = TOP)
jul_box.bind('<Return>')

def jd2gd(jd):
  global string
  jd=jd+0.5
  Z=int(jd)
  F=jd-Z
  alpha=int((Z-1867216.25)/36524.25)
  A=Z + 1 + alpha - int(alpha/4)

  B = A + 1524
  C = int( (B-122.1)/365.25)
  D = int( 365.25*C )
  E = int( (B-D)/30.6001 )

  dd = B - D - int(30.6001*E) + F

  if E<13.5:
            mm=E-1

  if E>13.5:
            mm=E-13

  if mm>2.5:
            yyyy=C-4716

  if mm<2.5:
            yyyy=C-4715

  months=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  daylist=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  daylist2=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

  h=int((dd-int(dd))*24)
  min =int((((dd-int(dd))*24)-h)*60)
  sec=86400*(dd-int(dd))-h*3600-min*60

  # Now calculate the fractional year. Do we have a leap year?
  if (yyyy%4 != 0):
            days=daylist2
  elif (yyyy%400 == 0):
            days=daylist2
  elif (yyyy%100 == 0):
            days=daylist
  else:
            days=daylist2

  hh = 24.0*(dd % 1.0)
  min = 60.0*(hh % 1.0)
  sec = 60.0*(min % 1.0)

  dd =  dd-(dd%1.0)
  hh =  hh-(hh%1.0)
  min =  min-(min%1.0)

  if hh < 10:
    hh = '0%s'%str(int(hh))
  else:
      hh = int(hh)
  if min < 10:
    min = '0%s'%str(int(min))
  else:
      min = int(min)
  if sec < 10:
    sec = '0%s'%str(int(sec))
  else:
      sec = int(sec)

  string = "%s/%s/%s  %s:%s:%s UTC" % (str(int(mm)), str(int(dd)), str(yyyy), str(hh),               str(min), str(sec))
  print string
  ##############
  return string
  ##############


def j2ghandler():
  jul = float(jul_box.get())

  #####################
  var.set(jd2gd(jul))
  #####################

j2g_button = Button(time_calc, text='Convert Julian\n to Gregorian', command = j2ghandler, width= 25, pady=5).pack(side=TOP)

#Draw Time String on Canvas
var = StringVar()
var.set(string)
label = Label(time_calc, textvariable=var)
label.pack(side=TOP)

##############################
time_calc.mainloop()
##############################
```

Basically, the key was to make `jd2gd` return `string` and then use that to update the label variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that this GUI module (like almost all) is event-driven, what means functions are called whenever some event occurs (button clicked, etc.) and this is all made by mainloop of Tkinter.

In your case: past your definition code (all that `time_calc = Tk()` and on) you start loop; then, when event of button clicked fires, it leads to call of binded function (`j2ghandler()`). From now application waits for it to return, and goes back to its loop.

### Solution

I assume you wanted to change text of label that's below button, when it's pushed (time gets converted).

You need to set label's value in event-called function; here, after printing:

```
def jd2gd(jd):
    #global string
    ...
    print string
    var.set(string)
    #return
```

Note: Commented lines are not needed.

Label gets changed without must of recreating `Label` object.
Also **Al.Sal** tip on globals is important here. *Request functions should never save state.*

Good luck with Python!

Answer (score 0):

I would stray away from using `global`, especially with `string` as it is ambiguous.

Have `jd2gd` return `string` (or whatever new name you decide to give it) and at the bottom of your program and include the code in `j2ghandler`. For example:

```
def j2ghandler():
    jul = float(jul_box.get())
    gregDate = jd2gd(jul)
    label = Label(time_calc, text=gregDate)
    label.pack(side=TOP)
```

You then remove the last 4 lines.

I haven't tested this so if there is an error, one solution would be to change the button to:

```
j2g_button = Button(time_calc, text='Convert Julian\n to Gregorian', command=lambda: j2ghandler(time_calc), width= 25, pady=5)
j2g_button.pack(side=TOP)
```

and `j2ghandler` to:

```
def j2ghandler(master):
    jul = float(jul_box.get())
    gregDate = jd2gd(jul)
    label = Label(master, text=gregDate)
    label.pack(side=TOP)
```

---

By the way...
You might want to change:

```
j2g_button = Button(time_calc, text='Convert Julian\n to Gregorian', command = j2ghandler, width= 25, pady=5).pack(side=TOP)
```

to:

```
j2g_button = Button(time_calc, text='Convert Julian\n to Gregorian', command = j2ghandler, width= 25, pady=5)
j2g_button.pack(side=TOP)
```

It works as it is but if you try to use `j2g_button` again it will return a `none` object.

Good luck!